# Fusioncharts — Highlight/shade a date range in a time series chart

Tags: charts, data-visualization, fusioncharts, timeserieschart

I have a graph created following [this example](https://www.fusioncharts.com/fusiontime/examples/dual-y-axis?framework=javascript). I want to highlight a particular region on the X-axis, say from May to Jul. Is this possible in Fusioncharts? I have already looked into reference zones (no such thing for X-axis) and vertical lines (not applicable to time series-type graphs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check timemarker feature of FusionTime where you define the events that occurred for a certain time frame on the x-axis, here is a snippet how to define it

```
 xaxis: {
      plot: "Time",
      timemarker: [
        {
          start: "Jul-1981",
          end: "Nov-1982",
          label:
            "Economic downturn was triggered by {br} tight monetary policy in an effort to {br} fight mounting inflation.",
          timeformat: "%b-%Y"
        }]
    }
```

To know more about it check this demo  - https://www.fusioncharts.com/fusiontime/examples/date-range-event-overlay?framework=javascript

Answer (score 1):

With the help of time marker functionality you can define specific or highlight date range in time series -

```
xAxis: {
plot: 'Time',
timemarker: [{
    start: 'Mar-1980',
    end: 'Jun-1983',
    label: 'US inflation peaked at 14.8%.',
    timeFormat: "%b-%Y",
    style: {
        marker: {
            fill: '#f8b8b7'
        }
    }
}]
```

}

[Demo JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/jntb04f9/)

To know more about Time Marker please refer the [docs](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/fusiontime-component/time-marker)